# Change VS Code search bar selected text color

Tags: visual-studio-code

The selected text color changes but I don't know why and since when, which causes the selected text color does not contrast

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKvc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have this issue: [The default Monokai highlight color is displayed incorrectly](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123044).  And it appears that a fix was made, but this may not appear in Stable builds until v1.57, in June 2021.

In the meantime you could test the fix in the Insiders Build  or try changing your theme from Monokai to something else.

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally I know what causes it, the problem was solved after I updated the vscode